# woocomerce - show products in category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories

I'm creating a shop. I have many Categories like:

cat1 (1)
– cat1.1 (3)
– cat1.1.1 (2)

If I go to cat1 I want to display only the 1 product that is in this category, not also the products in cat1.1 & cat1.1.1 and I want to display cat.1.1

And for cat 1.1 I want to show 3 Products and cat1.1.1

How can I do that? it should be dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put in functions.php file

```
function excludeChildCategory($wp_query) 
{
    if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['product_cat']) && $wp_query->is_main_query()) 
    {
        $wp_query->set('tax_query', array(
                array (
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'terms' => $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'],
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'include_children' => false
                )
            )
        );
      }
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'excludeChildCategory');
```

Comment: If I am on cat1. I only want to show up products from cat1, and not the products from child categories (not from cat 1.1 and not from cat1.1.1). And also for the other child categories

Comment: Please check the updated code, i hope it will solve your issue.